# How to grant privileges on mysql from Dockerfile?

Tags: mysql, docker, privileges

Is it possible to make define privileges for the MySQL server when you build from a dockerfile?

EDIT: Edited the title to ask how, and not if it is possible

Comment: Could yoy tell me how? I can't find anything useful. I've tried to use RUN in the dockerfile to run the grant all privileges command, but the container needs to be running for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

in the Dockerfile

```
COPY ./init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

according to section "Initializing a fresh instance"
in https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/